# getting the error ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am not able to `git push heroku master` anymore

I get the following error (after the bundle install and assets precompile step that looks like had no problem)

The error is the following:

```
remote: Verifying deploy............................
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to my-project.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/my-project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-project.git'
```

An idea what can be causing this ? Is it in the heroku side or git side ? (I am using bitbucket)

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at [the large number of questions similar to this one](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby+heroku+remote+rejected)?

Comment: Yes i did ! They all talk about different versions of the code between origin and local master. But in my case, everything seem up-to-date...

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while deploying to heroku. The most probable cause is that there is an error in you source code. Scroll up the transcript generated(from which you have copied the mentioned message)
I found: "

```
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: undefined local variable or method `heroRails' for main:Object"
```

because of a typing error. 
After correcting the source code commit and push.
'git push heroku master' will run and deploy succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests (`pre-receive hook declined`), the server you are pushing to has a pre-receive hook, i.e. a script that is ran before the push is completed to check some well-formedness properties. Your code does not satisfy these.

Search "heroku pre-receive hook" on SO or your favorite search engine to find issues that may cause this.